# Getting records from database, FROM a date TO a date

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'd like to obtain a record of a student's attendance from the "attendance" table. From a date to a date, e.g., from September 23, 2022, to December 10, 2022. Admin will enter the student's class and roll number, as well as a From date to date range.

Using his class and roll number. How to do this in Laravel 9 Thanks

```
this is the from through which a specific students record will be retirved.

 <form class="mt-3" method="POST" action="\record">
            @csrf
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Student Class</label>
                <input type="number" name="class" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Roll Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="roll number" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">From Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="from_date"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">To Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereBetween` in laravel to achieve this.

Suppose you have a model named `Student`.

You'd then do this in your controller:

```
$from = now();
$to = now()->addDays(5);

$studentAttendance = Student::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Which will get the students who have a date between `$from` and `$to` dates.